# Migrating phpBB3 users to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, phpbb, phpbb3

I need to migrate phpBB3 users to Drupal 7. Users must be able to authenticate within Drupal using their phpBB username/password combination.

Is there a way to 'translate' the passwords to Drupal 7 format?

I have access to both servers and databases. For the import to Drupal, I am currently using the Feeds module (CSV imports), but I would consider using another method / module if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After using it myself, I always recommend on [gConverter](http://gconverter.com/).
It sounds unreasonable, but they have great support, it is not expensive (I don't want them to change prices, so I don't tell that it is actually damn cheap...), and it actually works !

Comment: Yes I know this website. But if you look closer at the details it says: Solution for User passowrds: The phpBB Usernames will be moved without any changes. New passwords will be generated randomly and we will provide you with a gConverter tool to send these new passwords to owners via their email addresses. [...] So this is not a solution. In any case, I don't want to send passwords via e-mail and I have over 10K users, which is a problem when it comes to mailing out anything from a website.

Comment: Didn't know that. When I converted from bbpress to drupal using gConverter it handled the passwords properly.